# HTML editing with preview

Tags: html

Editing html is good but I really would like to have a way of fast previewing the changes that I made. Is there e.g. a script to open Chromium or refresh a site for that?

Comment: Look for impatient-mode

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have some options: http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Markdown#Impatient-mode the best for html looking to be [impatient-mode](https://github.com/skeeto/impatient-mode), it allows to see the changes in your browser while you type.

After intsallation (in melpa) it is just a matter of

```
M-x httpd-start
```

and

```
M-x impatient-mode
```

and then open your browser to http://localhost:8080/imp/

Comment: This seems to mirror what i see in emacs. I expected my browser to display the rendering of the html document that I am editing.

Comment: It is supposed to. Now testing I see a "forbidden" message. Maybe new browser policies prevent it from rendering. I'd like someone to confirm it still works on FF >= 83.

Answer (score 2):

You have many options depending on tools you use and setup you want. The first one does not need anything to be installed:

1. `M-x browse-url-of-buffer`
2. https://github.com/skeeto/skewer-mode
3. https://github.com/skeeto/impatient-mode
4. https://github.com/yukihr/Warp